# Interesting usages of function prototype scope

Tags: c++

According to http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/scope-regions-in-c/240002006

> A name has function prototype scope if it's declared in the function
>   parameter list of a function declaration that is not also a
>   definition. Its scope begins right after its declaration and runs to
>   the end of the parameter list.

Are there any interesting usages and tricks with this function prototype scope?

Comment: `template <class It> void f(It it, decltype(*it) v)` - `it` has "function prototype scope".

Comment: Just means you can't declare two function parameters in a prototype with the same name I think

Comment: The quote is actually wrong, or at least outdated, because the scope extends to the trailing return type, if any.

Comment: @Holt The article's year is  2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tricks? Sure. As Holt said:

```
template <class It>
void f(It it, decltype(*it) v);
```

But in my eyes this is less to permit tricks, and more so we can inherit rules defined elsewhere and use them to ban giving parameters the same name:

```
void f(int a, int a);  // ugh
```